# Force windows 7 to update dns through dhcp server?

Tags: bind, isc-dhcp, dynamic-dns

I have setup a new BIND9 to allow dynamic updates from my DHCP3 server. I am securing it using a DNSSEC key. Everything appears to work except when my windows workstation grabs an IP address it tries to update the dns records itself instead of going through the DHCP server. This is of course denied by BIND.

How can I stop my Windows box from trying to update the DNS on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Comment: You should probably add that this needs to be unset on all of the individual client computers in question.

Comment: I disabled that, I don't think it did anything I will have to check the syslog in the morning. Thanks.